# String length is getting wrong from two strings in java?

Tags: java, string, duplicates

Here i have two string name1 and name2 from that if letter is duplicated and least occurance that times has to delete.Eg: `String name1="raja"` and `name2="rani"` in that 'r' has to delete from both and 'a' occured 2 times in name1 and 1 time in name2 so only 'a' has to delete 1 time from name1 and name2 finally i need to get output as:'jani' and length is 4.But here length is coming three.This is my code.

```
String name1 = "raja";
String name2 = "rani";
for (int i = 0; i < name1.length(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < name2.length(); j++) {
        if (name1.charAt(i) == name2.charAt(j)) {
            name1 = name1.replace(name1.charAt(i), '\0');
            name2 = name2.replace(name2.charAt(j), '\0');
        }
    }
}
String result = name1 + name2;
String result = result.replaceAll("\0", "");
int resultLength = result.length(); //need to get 4.
```

your help will be appreciated.

Comment: your last `a` in `raja` was also deleted.

Comment: follow this tutorial it will help http://www.javaforschool.com/788673-program-to-remove-duplicate-characters-from-a-word/

Comment: what do you think happens when you put a 0 into a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
String name1 = "raja";
String name2 = "rani";
for (int i = 0; i < name1.length(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < name2.length(); j++) {
        if (name1.charAt(i) == name2.charAt(j)) {       
            name1 = name1.replaceFirst(String.valueOf(name1.charAt(i)), "#");
            name2 = name2.replaceFirst(String.valueOf(name2.charAt(j)), "#");
            break;

        }
    }
}
String result = name1 + name2;
result = result.replaceAll("#","");
int resultLength = result.length(); //need to get 4.
System.out.println(result);
System.out.println(resultLength);
```

I think the code is self explanatory, still if you didn't understood anything in the code, you can leave a comment.

Comment: Sarthak Mittal,when i change name1="krishna" and name2 as same rani then it is giving wrong length as 11 it should give 3

Comment: sorry i misread your question a little bit wait a few mins :)

Comment: Actually there is, because then more characters would get deleted from the second string if they occur afterwards too, was i clear, try removing that break and try the code with different outputs. :)

Answer (score 1):

You have *way* too much code for such a simple task.

In pseudo code:

- for each char in name1

  - remove 1 occurrence of that char from name2

In java, not much more than the pseudo:

```
for (int i = 0; i < name1.length(); i++)
    name2 = name2.replaceFirst(name1.substring(i, i + 1), "");
```

That's all the code you need for the character manipulation as stated.

#### Edit:

I just realised it can be done much more neatly:

```
for (String letter : name1.split("(?<=.)"))
    name2 = name2.replaceFirst(letter, "");
```

The regex passed to split splits after each letter - neatly giving an array of letters as strings.